# Can I access the names of instance variables in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c

If I have a class thus:

```
@interface Fields : NSObject {
@public
NSString* location;
NSString* keywords;
}
@end
```

Can I access not only the values of location & keywords but also the names of these variables? i.e. "location" and "keywords" ? These names will be passed between computers and are not displayed to users.

Or... do I use a dictionary and keep code and data separate?

Comment: I think it's different in that there is a difference between properties and instance variables. Closely related though!

Comment: @Carl While you can do so, I'd recommend against it.  This kind of meta-programming is really a bit alien to the design patterns of ObjC and going down this kind of a route will generally end in painful debugging and maintenance issues.

Comment: thanks @bbum. I agree with you that, while this kind of access is fully supported in some languages, we're off the beaten Obj C path. I am going to use a different approach and duplicate the variable names in data instead. I'll leave Aaron Brager's answer marked as accepted for those wanting such a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a list of ivars for a class using [`class_copyIvarList`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/class_copyIvarList).

For example:

```
unsigned int count = 0;
Ivar* ivars = class_copyIvarList([self class], &count);
for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    NSLog(@"%@::%s", NSStringFromClass([self class]), ivar_getName(ivars[i]));
}
free(ivars);
```

Comment: don't forget to `#import <objc/runtime.h>`